# Clear previous data before request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, duplicates, asp.net-ajax

I've got an HTML-template which loads data from controller's array and keeps them in a table. Also I have a directive, which makes transclusion for table rows. The data array is being filled on API-requests. After the new requests I've got the request results merged in my table. One set of rows is being added for each request instead of clearing previous results.

I've debugged over my controller code to check the state of my array and it's being cleared before each request. That's for sure. However new results are added to previous. I think the reason might be in my template of transclusion directive.

The template looks like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="results" ng-show="results.length > 0">
            <table class="table result-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>1</th>
                        <th>2</th>
                        <th>3</th>
                        <th>4</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="result in results" my-result></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code of my transclusion directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('myResult',
['$compile',
function ($compile) {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/app/templates/resultTemplate.html',
        compile: function (tElement, tAttr, transclude) {
            var contents = tElement.contents().remove();
            var compiledContents;
            return function (scope, iElement, iAttr) {
                if (!compiledContents) {
                    compiledContents = $compile(contents, transclude);
                }
                compiledContents(scope, function (clone, scope) {
                    iElement.replaceWith(clone);
                });
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

And finally the template used for transclusion:

```
<tr class="big-bord">
    <td colspan="4"><h3>{{result.fullName}}</h3></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="item in result.items">
    <td>{{item.value1}}</td>
    <td>{{item.value2}}</td>
    <td>{{item.value3}}</td>
    <td>{{item.value4}}</td>
</tr>
```

How can I clear my results before each API requests?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?  According to the Angular 1.4 docs, compile(transclude) has been deprecated.

Comment: jbrown, I use Angular 1.5.7. What comes instead of transclusion?

Comment: The angular docs state "use the transclude function that is passed to the link function instead".  Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still not sure if it will solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem. It turned out that multiple <tbody> tags are allowed within one table. So I just moved my ng-repeat to <tbody> tag:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="result in results">
    <tr class="big-bord">
        <td colspan="4"><h3>{{result.fullName}}</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in result.items">
        <td>{{item.value1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value2}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value3}}</td>
        <td>{{item.value4}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

So, I don't need any directives at all.

Comment: If you want to avoid multiple `tbody`, you can use `ng-repeat-start` on the first row and `ng-repeat-end` on the second row. [More information](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).